# How do you change the programming language of an existing Visual Studio project - NOT convert the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just re-arranged a Visual Studio solution. It used to be just one project in one solution. I created two new empty projects and moved some code files into them, so I now have a solution with three projects.

Now I notice that I accidentally chose the wrong programming language for one of the projects; it got to be VB but the entire solution is C#. It is a Windows Service project.

I want to change the programming language of that project to C#, without performing any type of conversion of the code etc. The code is already written in C# - it's just that Visual Studio doesn't know that :)

I've seen many similar questions but they all seem to involve re-factoring/translating code - I just want to change the project setting.

Comment: Just recreate the project and re-add the files

Comment: In the new project format (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk`, used for .NET Core, but also available for Framework if edited manually) this is trivial: the language is implicitly determined by the extension, so you can just rename the `.vbproj` to `.csproj`. In the old format, this involves editing and rearranging GUIDs and is not really worth doing.

Comment: @AFriend Yeah that is of course a possibility, but let's say it was very complex and time consuming to arrange all files and folders again. I'll keep it as an emergency solution.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Will try that!

Comment: @JeroenMostert Curiously enough the result of changing the extension of the project file in this case is: Nothing. Solution still "works", but language is still VB.

Comment: Yes, that's because it'll be using the old format (with a ton of semi-readable XML, instead of the new format, which has only a smattering of much more readable XML). The old format codes the type of project in the project type GUID. Create two new empty projects in VS, one VB and one CS, and do a diff, to see what I mean. Patching the GUID from VB to CS might be enough to fix it, or it might not be.

Comment: An example of a minimal project file in the new style: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"><PropertyGroup><OutputType>Exe</OutputType><TargetFramework>net45</TargetFramework></PropertyGroup></Project>`. Everything else is inferred and implicit (all files in the same directory and subdirectories will become part of the project). The old style is infinitely more verbose and won't fit in a comment.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I see what you mean, thanks a lot for the input! I noticed now that there are some auto created files in my folders which appear to be specific to VB projects. Thus, even if I managed to convert it to C#, I'd still have some crap left from when it was VB. I think I'll use the emergency exit and try to re-do the whole process. Hope I can locate a copy from the right time...

Answer (score 0):

In line with what the comments say, the answer to this question is: You don't.

But let me expand a bit on that :) 
The OP (me) was looking for a way to change the language of a VB Windows Service to C#. The aim was to get an identical setup, as creating a C# project from the start and moving code files into it, would have given. But I now realize that the choice of language has more impact than just rendering your existing code files un-buildable - it also creates files and folders specific to the language:

[image: items in new VB service project]

I should have known, but I didn't think about it since I was in the VS GUI all the time.

So if your intention is same as mine, the answer is no it can't be done by simply changing some setting in Visual Studio.

Why did I care?
I had spent some time rearranging a bunch of existing files and folders after creating the project, before I realized I got the wrong language. So I wanted to avoid doing it all over again. Though - I would say that it's not worth it. I ended up doing it from the start.

If you make the mistake I made, and you somehow REALLY want to change the language of a project, it probably IS doable (see comments above). It is likely to be fairly complicated, and it WILL require you to get in among the files and delete stuff added by the project template. Exactly how to do it would vary depending on project type and product version.

Footnote: Different types of projects/solutions might behave differently - other project types could be simpler to change the language of.

Footnote 2: Answering myself feels awkward, and it's kind of a non answer. But I still feel it could help someone in my situation. Don't flame me if you disagree; but do let me know! :-)